# Page that lets the user import file does not work - PHP

Tags: php, html, json, import

I am trying to develop a page that lets the user import a JSON file and redirects him to the home page where the information from the file is displayed. I did the page and it makes no connection with the database, the page stays static, and also I get this warning:
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\stsbootstrap\import.php on line 36
Notice: Undefined index: samplefile.json in C:\xampp\htdocs\stsbootstrap\import.php on line 32
Notice: Undefined index: samplefile.json in C:\xampp\htdocs\stsbootstrap\import.php on line 33
I am kinda lost about what I am getting wrong as I am doing this for the first time and I am working off PHP documentation.. Any ideas?

```
$serverName = "localhost";
$username ="";
$password="";
$dbName = "sts";
try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$serverName; dbname=$dbName", $username, $password);
}
catch (PDOException $e){
    $errorInfo= $e->errorInfo;
    echo "Database error " . $errorinfo[1];
}

//importing file    
 if(isset($_POST['buttonImport'])) {
copy($_FILES['jsonFile']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/'.$_FILES['jsonFile']['samplefile.json']);
$data = file_get_contents('uploads/'.$_FILES['jsonFile']['samplefile.json']);
$ticket = json_decode($data);

foreach ($ticket as $ticket) {
    $stmt=('INSERT INTO
    tickets(subject, description, team, status) VALUES(:subject, :description, :team, :status)');
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($stmt);
    $stmt->bindValue('subject', $ticket->subject);
    $stmt->bindValue('description', $ticket->description);
    $stmt->bindValue('team', $ticket->team);
    $stmt->bindValue('status', $ticket->status);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "Your upload was successful!"; 
    header ('home.php');
    
}
 }
    ?>
```

```html
 <body>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="padding: 0 16px;">
                 Please upload a JSON file here:</br><input type="file" class="btn btn-light" 
                name="jsonFile">
            <br>
            </br>

        <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="offset-sm-2 col-sm-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Import" name="buttonImport" class="btn btn-primary"/>
        </div>
      </div>
        
        </form>
    </body>
```

```
Here's my database too:
```

[database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GOpq.png)

Comment: `foreach ($ticket as $ticket)` is of course not a good idea, that will _overwrite_ your array variable with a single item, once the loop executes for the first time. Choose a different variable name for the `as …` part.

Comment: `file_get_contents('uploads/'.$_FILES['jsonFile']` A posted file is not in your upload directory. I think you need to make sure your file uploading and reading is correct

Comment: How do you know if the file is uploading and reading correctly?